# WCF structure soap message

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

i have a problem. How can I realize a similar structure in WCF?

```
<MessageData>
   <AppData>
     <Name>Eugene</Name>
     <SureName>Tolpygo</SureName>
   </AppData>
</MessageData>
```

i tried to use [DataContract] and [DataMember] but it's not work.

[UPDATE 1]
I need to do soap web service.

My Code

```
public MessageDataType Get()
    {
        MessageDataType MessageData = new MessageDataType();
        return MessageData;
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class MessageDataType
    {   [DataMember]
        AppDataType AppData = new AppDataType(); 
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class AppDataType
    {  
        [DataMember]
        string Name = "Eugene";
        [DataMember]
        string Surname = "Tolpygo";
    }
```

Comment: paste the code of your try and we can tell you what's wrong

Comment: What do you mean "How can I realize a similar structure"? Do you mean model that structure in code? Or do you mean you want your service to return that exact xml? Please explain exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: @TomRedfern i want to my service return a xml structure that I wrote above

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger i wrote my code. I am sorry that I did this before.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get it very well, but try to use ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml in attribute WebGet()

> [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml]